# Select MAX among multiple tables in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to list patients and their most recent primary insurance benefits.  I have three tables involved,

> patients (contains patient demographic data)
>   benefits (contains insurance benefits information) 
>   rel_pat_ben (matches primary keys of patient table with corresponding key on benefits table)

I almost solved the problem with this:

> SELECT p.patient_id, MAX(b.benefits_id), b.effective_date
>   FROM patients AS p
>   LEFT JOIN rel_pat_ben AS rpb USING(patient_id)
>   LEFT JOIN benefits AS b ON (rpb.benefits_id=b.benfits_id AND b.order='primary')
>   GROUP BY patient_id

Using MAX seemed to work as the id field is auto-incremented, but I realized my problem when I found cases where a record that has a lower id was edited with newer information.  So really, I need to check the 'effective_date' field.

Is there a way to return just one record per patient that contains only the most recent insurance benefits?

Comment: I added the `greatest-n-per-group` tag.  This class of SQL question has been answered many, many times.

Comment: Thanks Bill!  I promise I looked diligently for an answer before asking.  I found many questions that were similar, but none that solved my exact problem.  Hopefully this will help the next person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will select the maximum effective_date, if it exists, for every patient:

```
SELECT p.patient_id, MAX(b.effective_date)
FROM
  patients AS p INNER JOIN rel_pat_ben AS rpb USING(patient_id)
  INNER JOIN benefits AS b ON (rpb.benefits_id=b.benfits_id AND b.order='primary')
GROUP BY
  p.patient_id
```

and this will select last benefit for every patient:

```
SELECT p.patient_id, b.*
FROM
  patients AS p INNER JOIN rel_pat_ben AS rpb USING(patient_id)
  INNER JOIN benefits AS b ON (rpb.benefits_id=b.benfits_id AND b.order='primary')
WHERE
  (p.patient_id, b.effective_date) IN (
    SELECT p.patient_id, MAX(b.effective_date)
    FROM
      patients AS p INNER JOIN rel_pat_ben AS rpb USING(patient_id)
      INNER JOIN benefits AS b ON (rpb.benefits_id=b.benfits_id AND b.order='primary')
    GROUP BY
      p.patient_id
  )
```

I'm using INNER JOINS so if there are no benefits for a patient, it won't be returned.

Comment: Thank you!  Your second solution works beautifully.  The first example also works as you described, but does not give me the `benefits_id` that corresponds (which I need).  If I add it to the SELECT portion, it will return the first `benefits_id` with the highest `effective_date`, even though that date does not belong to that `benefits_id`.  Again, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

What if you try adding

```
ORDER BY b.effective_date DESC
```

after the GROUP BY clause?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I did try it, with both DESC and ASC parameters, but it still just gives me the first record, not the newest.